# How to simplify only one side of an equality?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose we have two expressions and `==` between them. I want to simplify only the right-hand side. What should I do?

Comment: Also, `#[[1]] == Simplify[#[[2]]] &@equation` or `ReplacePart[equation, 2 -> Simplify[equation[[2]]]]`

Comment: Alternative: `Simplify[equation[[2] ]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann did not you forget a brace?

Comment: @Anixx: Yes, `Simplify[equation[[2]] ]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
equation = y + z  == D[Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x], x]
```

[image]

You can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[Simplify, equation, {2}]
```

[image]